# gpt partitions for windows 7 and ubuntu dual boot on 4TB HDD (UEFI MB)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have an empty HDD with 4TB capacity. I am trying to create the gpt partitions using GParted so I can install windows 7 and ubuntu. What I want is to be able to utilize the entire 4TB space. I want to allocate 200GB to windows, 200GB to ubuntu and the rest I want to leave it as a shared space for both OS. I have seen numerous answers on how to install ubuntu on a windows machine but I think the best way of doing it starting with a clean HDD (large one >2TB) is not very clear. All answers greatly appreciated.

-Goutham

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please make clear what is actually being asked

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partition table GPT style, and the appropriate partitions. Install Windows then Ubuntu. I can't recall off hand if Windows 7 forcibly requests an MSR partition but if it does just delete the Windows partition reboot the installation disc and choose the empty space, Windows will then be able to automatically create an MSR in addition to the Windows Partition.

Partition 1 = UEFI = an FAT32 partition at least 128MB better yet 512MB in size with "boot" flag. Primary style.

Partition 2 = Windows = NTFS 200GB. Primary style.

Partition 3 = Ubuntu = EXT4 200GB . Primary style.

Partition 4 = DATA = NTFS primary style.